# Wiring VPN router

Tags: vpn, pptp

I just bought a Cisco RV-130 VPN router, and I'm trying to figure out how to plug it over my home network.

I usually use standard home router with built-in VPN Host. but this time I use a external VPN router.

I've been able to configure the VPN router so it can take PPTP connection from With-In the LAN, but keep failing when attempting to connect from outside my LAN. I mean from the outside world via Internet.

The question: 
Does the VPN router can be wired "After" the "main" router. considering that the firewall port fowarding is correctly configured (Ports 1723, 47)

`VPN Router <---> Home Router <-----> ISP Modem
(10.35.0.5)       (10.35.0.1)         (x.x.x.x)`

---

Here is my setting, can could tell me if something wrong

[image]https://www.dropbox.com/s/bnmx2vsvuh134j3/img1.png?dl=0

[image]https://www.dropbox.com/s/k588bop63bva4bc/img2.png?dl=0

Comment: I'd check to see that you can reach it from the outside of "Home Router" first before you bother trying from the internet.  Both ISP modem and Home Router are going to have to be configured to handle the necessary forwarding.

Comment: Is there any tool that I can use to test if the connection can reach the VPN Router?

Comment: I'm not sure this is your problem, but GRE (the encapsulation protocol) is neither TCP nor UDP and cannot be handled by port forwarding at that layer - it is an IP encapsulation *protocol* number 47, not a port number.  I would see if you can define 10.35.0.5 as your DMZ host (on the DMZ tab) or on NAT passthrough (that's an ASUS router?) and get rid of that port forwarding...

Comment: Yes it is a ASUS. I've try "TelNet  *ISP-IP-ADDRESS* 1723" from within my network and a blank screen appear (I'm assuming that work behavior), then I try the same command but from the Outside World, and telnet tell me that the connection to host fail. (Tried with and without DMZ)

Comment: Try it with NAT passthrough to the cisco IP, with the DMZ disabled, port forwarding *only* for TCP port 1723.  You'll probably want NAT traversal on the Cisco as well.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply. 
I ended up by wiring the VPN Router BEFORE the Home Router and then thing began to start working.

I guest that the ASUS Router did not foward the connection correctly.
Either with DMZ On or Off, or using VPN Passthrought